# What makes count(*) query to run for 30 sec?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a MS SQL table with over 250 million rows.  Whenever I execute the following query

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name`

it takes over 30 seconds to get me the output.  Why is it taking so much time?  Does this do a count when I query?  I'm assuming till date that it stores this information somewhere (probably in the table meta data.  I m not sure if table meta even exists).

Also, I would like to know if this query is IO/Processor/Memory intensive?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a primary key or any indexes on the table?

Comment: Yes, I do.  I have got a primary key on the id and I have got indexes on the id as well as date.  But, when I use select count(*) without any condition, not sure if the primary key or index makes any difference.  I might be complete wrong as well.

Comment: Yes it always has to count all rows from somewhere (will use the narrowest non filtered index available). It never retrieves this from the table metadata. You can query the metadata yourself though if you want a not guaranteed accurate or transactionally consistent figure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you execute `SELECT COUNT(*) from TABLE` SQL server actually goes through the table and counts all rows. To get estemated row count on one or more tables you can run the following query which gets stored information and returns in under 1 sec.

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) TableName, st.row_count
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats st
WHERE index_id < 2
ORDER BY st.row_count DESC
```

Read more about it here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187737.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No, sql server dosen't store this information. It computes it every query. But it can cache execution plan to emprove perfomace. So, if you want to get results quickly, you need a primary key at least.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for approximation counts on tables and your version is greater than or equal to SQL Server 2005, you can simply use:

```
SELECT t.NAME AS 'TableName'
,s.Name AS 'TableSchema'
,p.rows AS 'RowCounts'
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s 
  ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.indexes i 
  ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.partitions p 
  ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
WHERE 
t.is_ms_shipped = 0
GROUP BY
t.NAME, s.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
s.Name, t.Name
```

Doing a count(*) would only consume a small amount of memory/processor.  It isn't that big of an operation in terms of database functions.

Answer (score 0):

As for what SQL server is doing and how expensive it is, you can look this up yourself. In SSMS enable the execution plan button for the query and run a `select count(*)`. You will see that the server actually does an index scan (full table scan). (I would have expected the PK to be used for that, but in my test case it used some other non-clustered index.).

To get a feel for the cost right-click your query editor window, select `Query Options... -> Execution -> Advanced` and activate the check boxes for `SET STATISTICS TIME` and `SET STATISTICS IO`. The messages tab will contain information regarding IO and timing after you re-executed the select statement.

Also note that a select count(*) is quite aggressive in terms of shared locks it uses. To guarantee the result the whole table will be locked with a `shared lock`.

A very fast, lock-free alternative is to use the meta data for the table. The count you get from the meta-data is almost always accurate, but there is no guarantee.

```
USE <database_name,,>
GO

SELECT ddps.row_count
FROM   sys.indexes AS i
       INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
         ON i.object_id = o.object_id
            AND o.name = '<your_table,,>'
       INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS ddps
         ON i.object_id = ddps.object_id
            AND i.index_id = ddps.index_id
WHERE  i.index_id = 1
```

This is a SSMS template. Copy this into a query window and hit CTRL+SHIFT+M to get a dialog that asks you for values for database_name and table_name.